# Move zend framework project from apache to windows-server-2008

Tags: zend-framework, windows-server-2008

I developed a website (Zend Framework 1.x runs the site) on XAMPP and my webserver runs on linux, so htaccess was available, all works fine. Now, my client want to move the project on his own webspace - a Windows Server 2008 with PHP installed.

What do I have to do now?
Where can I find more information? (it is hard to use Google due to existing Zend Server and so most hits are related to this matter)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can start here: http://blog.richardknop.com/2011/09/making-zend-framework-run-under-iis/

The really important thing to pay attention to is how install and configure the rewrite module, as your current .htacces will not work with IIS.